# Вопросительный знак или многоточие уместнее в ниже представленном риторическом вопросе?

Tags: пунктуация

Помните анекдот с бородой? Далее идет текст. Или... Помните анекдот с бородой... Далее идет текст.

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите сформулировать риторический вопрос, то вопросительный знак нужен по определению. В данном конкретном случае без этого знака получается императив, поэтому, если нужно избежать формы вопроса, нужно добавить что-либо превращающее императив в повествование (вместо многоточия можно и точку поставить, если не нужна недоговоренность):

> Вы, *наверное*, помните тот анекдот с бородой...

или:

> Вы *ведь* помните тот анекдот с бородой...

Answer (score 1):

Форма ***помните*** может быть личной формой или формой повелительного наклонения:  **Помните об этом (повелительная форма). Вы помните об этом (вопрос)?**

Избавиться от этих двух значений можно, если считать ***помните*** вводным предложением со значением обращения к собеседнику. Тогда можно поставить точку.

**Помните, есть такой анекдот с бородой.**